# Querying For ReferenceOnce Documents By ObjectId() Works for One But Not Many

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony

I have two documents, Question and Answer. The Question class has an `$answers` property defined as `@MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Answer", cascade="all")`. The Answer class has a `$question` property defined as `@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Question")`. Both classes have an `$id` property defined as `@MongoDB\Id`.

I need to return a partial array of all the answers for a single question, say in groups of 10.

I've tried a number of different approaches, all with varying results. None of the approaches have yielded what I need.

---

**Querying the Question repo**

```
$question = $this->getDocumentManager()
  ->getRepository(self::QUESTION_REPO)
  ->find($id);

$answers = array($questions->getAnswers());
```

That'll get me the answers but not 10 at a time.

**Querying the Answer repo (version 1)**

```
$question = $this->getQuestion($id); // works just fine
$answers = $this->getDocumentManager()
  ->createQueryBuilder(self::ANSWER_REPO)
  ->field('question.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($question->getId()))
  ->getQuery()
  ->execute();
```

This query will return an empty object.

**Querying the Answer repo (version 2)**

```
$question = $this->getQuestion($id);
$answers = $this->getDocumentManager()
  ->createQueryBuilder(self::ANSWER_REPO)
  ->field('question')->references($question)
  ->getQuery()
  ->execute();
```

This query will return an empty object too.

**Querying the Answer repo (version 3)**

```
$question = $this->getQuestion($id);
$answers = $this->getDocumentManager()
  ->getRepository(self::ANSWER_REPO)
  ->findBy(array('question.id' => $question->getId()));
```

This query will return an empty object too.

**Querying the Answer repo (version 4)**

```
$question = $this->getQuestion($id);
$answer = $this->getDocumentManager()
  ->getRepository(self::ANSWER_REPO)
  ->findOneBy(array('question.id' => $question->getId()));
  // note: 'question.id' and not 'question.$id'
```

This query **will** return the expected object - a single Answer - to my great surprise.

---

So, the question I have is, what am I missing?

I'd prefer not to "embed" my documents, although I've read that it's easier to query on embedded documents that way. Maybe I can embed the Question in the Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Query::execute()` and `DocumentRepository::findBy()` will return a Cursor so it will not contain any actual data inside the object. Are you sure that it is empty? If you start iterating over the $answers or do `$answers->count()` it should work.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. Now I have to wait until later to test.

Comment: I feel foolish not debugging through properly. Had I seen this was a Cursor I would have simply appended a `->toArray()` and been off to the races. Thank you.